# Convert html to aspx

Tags: html, asp.net

Is there any tool or code to convert HTML files to .ASPX?

Elaboration to earlier question: I am looking for tool or code that automatically converts HTML controls to .ASPX server controls without having to manually change each control, i.e.,  something that will take an HTML page as input, parse, and output as an .ASPX page with server controls.

Comment: Sure. just change the extension from .html to .aspx.

Answer (score 6):

No conversion needed. Just change *.html to *.aspx.

If you want parts of the HTML page to become dynamic, there's more work involved then.

Comment: i'm looking for html to aspx controls, any tool or a code which can convert the html controls to aspx controls. renaming from html to aspx doesn't help converting the internal code.

Comment: @vinod The reason I asked is because HTML doesn't have server side controls. It only has its markup. ASP.NET outputs the same HTML markup. It sounds like your requirements are more complicated than your question makes them appear.

Answer (score 3):

No, ASP.NET code is embedded in your regular HTML code, so your default web pages will have the extension .aspx but there are a few other things you need to do to get a ASP.NET site up and running.

Check out this link with some help on how to get started with ASP.NET
http://www.asp.net/get-started/

Also, here's one of my [favorite books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590598911) on the subject that really helped me learn more about ASP.NET (you might want to find a version 4.0 book though if you are working with the new features of ASP.NET.)

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple to convert `.html` to `.aspx`

if you just change the extension from `.html` to `.aspx` ,

1. Sometimes it leads to some unexpected exception handling, that says as , `file cannot open or corrupted` You will just have the `filename.aspx` page(design and source) BUT WILL not get the `filenmae.aspx.vb` page(coding).

So better follow these steps :

1. Open the `.html` file in a `notepad` and copy the contents.
2. Create a new `webform` in `visualstudio` (with masterpage)
3. Goto `source` page and erase the default contents and paste the copied contents
4. Save it. execute it .

**Note(Imp):** Do not forget to keep ur `webform controls` , `jscripts`, `css(stylesheets)`, `images(if any)` within the project created